# How to translate "screen ratio" in French?

Tags: anglicismes, comparaison-de-langues

Just a simple question : what is the best way to translate screen ratio in French?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, we'll use *[format d'image](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17018654)*, or if context is clear, only *format*. For example:

> Écran de résolution 1600 x 900 et de format 16:9.

If you want to emphasize that it's a ratio, you can also use *rapport d'aspect* or *rapport de l'image*.

Comment: No, this is technically wrong. It might be understood by the general public, but _format de l'image_ would be the _file format_ (i.e. JPEG, PNG…) if talking about computer files. _Format de l'image_ is the proper term for the _ratio_ only [in the context of cinema](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format_d%27image). Considering **screen** ratio places us most likely in the first category.

Comment: This might be one of the "across the pond" differences, because everywhere I look in Canadian references give me *format d'image* for computer monitors. It's also universally used by people.

Comment: The OP didn't mention this, but his profile says he's from Quebec, so a Canadian answer is probably the right one.

Comment: Ok. My own answer, and the critic of this one, are indeed for FR-fr  :)

Comment: No no, I was living in Quebec when I registered on this website, but I am fro France. Anyway, I think format is convenient here. Thanks.

Comment: Ne devrait-ce pas plutôt être *format d'écran* ?

Comment: @RomainVALERI L'écran est l'objet, et donc ne change pas de dimensions, alors que la résolution et le rapport de l'image peuvent être modifiés. Par exemple, le lecteur VLC permet de visionner des vidéos en 1:1, 4:3, 16:9, 5:3 ou même 2.35:1.

Comment: @Kareen Je parlais ici de l'écran logique et non de l'écran physique. Une image, en revanche, c'est autre chose : c'est un fichier. Il ne me semble pas correct de parler de format d'image pour évoquer le ratio d'affichage général... Peut-être faut-il préférer *ratio d'affichage* ?

Comment: @RomainVALERI Je ne parlais pas d'une image, mais de l'image projetée par l'écran, comme on parle de l'image projetée par un téléviseur. Les boutiques électroniques indiquent d'ailleurs bien *format d'image* ou *de l'image* dans la liste des caractéristiques des écrans qu'elles ont à vendre.

Comment: Dans le contexte spécifique d'une image de télévision, effectivement, la confusion n'est pas possible. Par contre, cette idée n'est pas présente dans la question initiale, et en informatique le choix du terme *image* introduit une confusion qui peut probablement être évitée.

Answer (score 2):

The technical term is [“ratio d'aspect”](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_d%27aspect).

Comment: It's just an [Anglicism](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ratio_d%E2%80%99aspect). *Rapport d'aspect* is just as technical and is based on French words.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez No, _rapport d'aspect_ is not technically correct, while _ratio d'aspect_ is. Compare the academic results for both searches: [rapport d'aspect](http://scholar.google.fr/scholar?lr=lang_fr&q=%22rapport+d%27aspect%22&hl=fr&as_sdt=0) brings up mostly results about physical objects, and no result in French-only pages. [Ratio d'aspect](http://scholar.google.fr/scholar?hl=fr&q=%22ratio+d%27aspect%22&btnG=&lr=lang_fr), on the other hand, brings French-specific results, almost all fitting the described context.

Comment: From what I could see in these pages, I don't think the distinction between physical or projected objects is relevant in any way. Google Scholar on French documents (even though google counts are often completely wrong) gives 30 times more results for "rapport d'aspect" (1120) than for "ratio d'aspect" (33). Google Scholar statistics are against you.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez No, they aren't. They simply display non-French results on "rapport d'aspect". Take a look at the right column and try to click on “Rechercher les pages en français”, it won't work. Moreover, this argument would be nonsense anyway: I am saying the term is technically wrong for the given meaning. That does not preclude it from being technically correct in a different, more often used, context.

Comment: Btw, if it's “not technically correct”, then it means something different. How is it different?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez It is different in the way that “rapport d'aspect” is much broader and more often used to describe physical objects’ length to width ratio. A [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=rapport%20d'aspect&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) will bring many results on tires, for example. “ratio d'aspect” will only find [digital images usage](http://www.google.com/search?q=rapport%20d'aspect&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). Hence, the “best way” to translate “screen ratio”, as in “the less ambiguous”, is “ratio d'aspect”.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format_d%27image) suggests *format d'image*. Another, maybe more technical term, could be *rapport d’aspect*, analogous to [rapport d'aspect de pixel](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapport_d%27aspect_de_pixel).

Comment: Downvoter: care to explain?

Comment: I did downvote (after your comment, though. I always justify them ;) ), because _rapport d'aspect_ is not technically correct. See my comment above about comparing academic search results: [rapport d'aspect](http://scholar.google.fr/scholar?lr=lang_fr&q=%22rapport+d%27aspect%22&hl=fr&as_sdt=0) brings up results mostly about physical objects, and no result in French-only pages. [Ratio d'aspect](http://scholar.google.fr/scholar?hl=fr&q=%22ratio+d%27aspect%22&btnG=&lr=lang_fr), on the other hand, brings French-specific results, almost all fitting the described context.

Comment: I don't see you point, more than half of those few “ratio d'aspects“ are used for physical objects as well. Anyway "rapport d'aspect" together with "pixel" yields 95 results where "ratio d'aspect" yields 15…

Comment: @MattiSG: While I do not agree, I appreciate that you (contrary to the two previous downvoters) explained your motivation. :)

Comment: I could imagine downvoting if I perceived this was the exact Kareen answer reposted (HTH).